# optimizing query with exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possible to optimize the following mysql query with EXISTS instead of IN function ?

```
Subscriber.first(:conditions => ["email IN(SELECT email from submissions WHERE url = ? AND confirmed != 0)", url], :order => "RANDOM()")
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on sql syntax for exists

```
EXISTS (SELECT email from submissions x WHERE url = ? AND confirmed != 0 AND x.email = email)
```